# datatable turns empty when i pass it to method

Tags: c#, methods, datatable

So i have a very simple function which goes through a table and find those rows that has the age columns between 2 numbers and then return a new table with the new rows. here is my function :

```
    private DataTable AgeFinder(int MiniAge, int MaxiAge, DataTable x)
    {
        //AFWT : Analyze From Which Table

        int count;
        DataTable dtAge = new DataTable();
        dtAge = x.Clone();
        int ageMin = MiniAge;
        int ageMax = MaxiAge;
        if (ageMin > ageMax)
        {
            int temp = ageMax;
            ageMax = ageMin;
            ageMin = temp;
        }
        int ageDr;

        count = 0;
        ageDr = 0;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = x;
        foreach (DataRow dr in x.Rows)
        {
            ageDr = Convert.ToInt16(x.Rows[count]["age "]);
            if (ageDr >= ageMin && ageDr < ageMax)
            {
                dtAge.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
            }
            count++;
        }
        lblCountThisQuery.Text = dtAge.Rows.Count.ToString();
        return dtAge;
    }
```

and here is how i call it:

```
    dtAge = AgeFinder(Convert.ToInt16(tbxMinAge.Text), Convert.ToInt16(tbxMaxAge.Text), AT);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dtAge;
```

now i can see that the AT is not empty but when i check the x (the table inside the method), its empty! why does this happen?

Comment: It shouldn't happen.  At all.  Is something else modifying that variable at the same time?  What *very specific* steps are you performing to debug this?  Right now my suspicion is that you're making a mistake in the debugger.

Comment: i didnt debug it. i keep getting an error on this line `ageDr = Convert.ToInt16(x.Rows[count]["age "]);` which says 'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types.'  the i tried to fill a datagridview from AT before passing it to the method and i see the datas are inside it but when i try to pass x to datagridview...it shows nothing which means its empty !!!

Comment: `"i didnt debug it"` - Well there's your first mistake.  Debug your code.  `"'Object cannot be cast from DBNull to other types"` - You're misinterpreting that error message.  Clearly `x` is *not* null, otherwise you'd get a `NullReferenceException`.  `x` has data.  The data in the table row/column is `null` and you're trying to convert it to an `Int16`.  Null can't be converted to a number.  Debug your code.